# Using Float Quantity in Order Menu

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to allow the usage of decimal quantities in the admin panel.

I had added the following code:

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval' );
```

But when I edit the order and try to change the quantity to decimals, after hitting update order, nothing happens and the following error comes in the console:

```
An invalid form control with name='order_item_qty[328]' is not focusable.
```

(328 is the item I Tried to edit)

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Using google chrome console, I had found out it is caused because the step attribute of the quantity fields on the items loop are not set to 0.1.
in the chrome source code I changed this:
<input type="number" step="1" min="0" autocomplete="off" name="order_item_qty[336]" placeholder="0" value="3.6" data-qty="3.6" size="4" class="quantity">
to this
<input type="number" step="0.1" min="0" autocomplete="off" name="order_item_qty[336]" placeholder="0" value="3.6" data-qty="3.6" size="4" class="quantity">
Is there a way to alter all the fields step attributes on the edit order window to 0.1?

Comment: I tried calling a function containing the following js:


const qtyClasses = document.getElementById('order_line_items').querySelectorAll('input.quantity');

// Change the text of multiple elements with a loop
qtyClasses.forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute('step', '0.1');
});

Comment: I am calling that js function using admin_footer action hook and it seems to work at first, but as soon as I edit the quantity and hit save, the step attribute returns to 1, and I again cannot save the order(Until I manually alter it in Chrome's source code)

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found the answer after digging in some Woocommerce Core Files:
Instead of using this:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', array( &$this, 'min_decimal' ), 99 );
```

I used this:

```
if(is_admin()){
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', array( &$this, 'admin_qty_step' ), 99 );
}
else{
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', array( &$this, 'min_decimal' ), 99 );
}
```

While the min_decimal method returns a string with a preset quantity step on the front-end and admin_qty_step returns "0.1" on the Back-end Interfaces.

Hope someone find this helpful